# Error on HttpRequest from Visualforce to standard SF domain

Tags: httprequest, cors

We are trying to make an HttpRequest from a custom button that is on a Visualforce page (custom View override) using Javascript. The request is being sent to a custom report. It contains a set of parameters that define filters for said report. This is resulting in the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

How can we accomplish this without having to dismantle the custom record override? We need to work with the report layout as well, which means we cannot use Apex to get the results.

Comment: Also adding the source and request domains to the CORS Whitelist doesn't make a difference. I don't understand why though.

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring because of cross domain. Salesforce hosts VF pages at

> c.{domain}.salesforce.com

and SF Resources are hosted at

> {domain}.salesforce.com

All current browsers does not allow cross domain referencing, without explicitly declaring "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in your API call.

if you are using Ajax to submit the call, set the header

```
$.ajax({
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            url: 'https://cs6.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8',
            type: 'POST',
```

Comment: Doing so gives this error: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Btw my request url is a standard report url: `https://sandbox.cs10.my.salesforce.com/00OJ0000000HBtM`